# Translating a WIN32 API message handler to MFC Message Map

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, windows-messages

I have a working windows API application with the CALLBACK proc function as follows:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK myTestCallBack(HWND hwndDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM    lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg) {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            HWND myRichEditHWND = GetDlgItem (hwndDlg, IDC_TEST);
            // set some text length limit
            SendMessage (myRichEditHWND, EM_LIMITTEXT, (WPARAM)MAX_STRING_LEN - 1, 0);
            // we need key and mouse events, see WM_NOTIFY
            SendMessage (myRichEditHWND, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, ENM_KEYEVENTS | ENM_MOUSEEVENTS);
            // misc options
            SendMessage (myRichEditHWND, EM_SETOPTIONS, ECOOP_OR, ECO_AUTOWORDSELECTION | ECO_SELECTIONBAR);
            SendMessage (myRichEditHWND, EM_SETZOOM, 64, 52);
            return TRUE;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (LOWORD (wParam)) {
                case IDOK:

                case IDCANCEL:
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                    EndDialog(hwndDlg, 0);
                    return TRUE;
            }
            break;
        case WM_NOTIFY:
            {
                MessageBox(hwndDlg, L"Testing Dialog", L"Test", S_OK);
                MSGFILTER*  msgf = (MSGFILTER*)lParam;
                if (msgf && msgf->nmhdr.hwndFrom == myRichEditHWND)
                    spellchecker_process (myRichEditHWND, msgf);
                return FALSE;
            }
        default:
            break; 
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

I am trying to integrate this functionality into an MFC application and I have carried out the following steps:

1. in the `OnInitialUpdate()` function i have:

   ```
   CWnd* pwndBody = GetDlgItem( IDC_EDIT_OUTBOUND_BODY );
   ASSERT( pwndBody );

   // Send messages to the Control, AA-20/01/2016
   // set some text length limit
   // richeditcrtl = (HWND)GetDlgItem( IDC_EDIT_OUTBOUND_BODY );
   pwndBody->PostMessage(EM_LIMITTEXT, (WPARAM)MAX_STRING_LEN - 1, 0);

   // we need key and mouse events, see WM_NOTIFY
   pwndBody->PostMessage(EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, ENM_KEYEVENTS | ENM_MOUSEEVENTS);

   // misc options
   pwndBody->PostMessage(EM_SETOPTIONS, ECOOP_OR, ECO_AUTOWORDSELECTION | ECO_SELECTIONBAR);

   pwndBody->PostMessage(EM_SETZOOM, 64, 52);
   ```
2. I declared a handler:

   ```
   afx_msg void OnSpellingError( NMHDR * pNotifyStruct, LRESULT * result );
   ```
3. defined the handler:

   ```
   void CAMCMVOutboundEmailView::OnSpellingError(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* Result) 
   {
        MSGFILTER*  msgf = (MSGFILTER*)pResult;
        spellchecker_process ((HWND)pwndBody, msgf);
   }
   ```
4. I provided a binding in the message map:

   ```
   ON_NOTIFY(NM_RCLICK, IDC_EDIT_OUTBOUND_BODY, OnSpellingError);
   ```

   because I want to call the spellchecker_process() function when `WM_NOTIFY` message is received just like it is in the WIN API CALLBACK function above.

I am new to MFC, but I know several things things are wrong and the obvious ones are:

- What should be the first parameter of the MFC `ON_NOTIFY` function? (it shouldn't be `NM_RCLICK`)
- How do I get the `LPARAM` parameter inside the message handler (`OnSpellingError`) as I need to cast it to the `MSGFILTER`?

In summary, I am just trying to implement the WIN API function in my MFC Application. Thanks

Comment: The notification code you're looking for is `EN_MSGFILTER` (note you're not actually checking for this in the Win32 version, which you should be).

Comment: Why di use use PostMessage instead of SendMessage? The behaviour you get is completely different.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Potter, Indeed that's the message I want and yes, xMRi, I have  change them to SendMessage.   I am now having a compatibility problem as the existing project's character encoding is multi-byte and the spell checking library has to be Unicode because of multiple foreign languages support. any ideas for gracefully converting between Character Encoding will be highly appreciated. thanks guys..